# Windows 10 tablet mode Registry setting: 'When this device automatically switches tablet mode on or off'

Tags: registry, windows-10, tablet

Tablet mode settings are found in the registry under [HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell]

The two important keys for you are TabletMode and SignInMode (you may have to create them).

TabletMode:

```
0 = Off
1 = On
```

SignInMode:

```
0 = "Automatically switch to Tablet Mode"
1 = "Go to the desktop"
2 = "Remember what I used last"
```

But I can't find any key for the "When this device automatically switches tablet mode on or off'

Does anyone know what setting I need to control this?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new DWORD value in [HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell] called ConvertibleSlateModePromptPreference

set to 0 for "Don't ask me and don't switch"

set to 1 for "Always ask me before switching" (default)

set to 2 for "Don't ask me and always switch"